# Security for angularfire

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get rid of an error which arises on posting a new entry to an angularfire array. The array holds reports, this array should be able to be written to, but not read from. The rules I have are as follows:

```
  "reports":{
      ".write":"(auth != null)",
     "$report_id":{
        //".write":"(auth != null)",// << commented out part
        ".validate":"!data.exists() && newData.exists() && newData.hasChildren(['reason', 'reportedUser', 'reportingUser', 'time'])",
        "reason":{
           ".validate":"newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
        },
        "reportedUser":{
           ".validate":"newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 30"
        },
        "reportingUser":{
           ".validate":"auth.uid === newData.val()"
        },
        "time":{
           ".validate":"newData.val() <= now"
        },
        "$other":{
           ".validate":false
        }
     }
  }
```

I am calling the write to this array from within a function, the contents of which is as follows:

```
        var reportsArray = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(FBaseURL + "/reports/"));        

        reportsArray.$add(reportData)
            .then(function(ref) {
                console.log('user reported');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error:", error);
            });
```

Whichever write rule I comment out in rules (also un-commenting the other), the write is successful but the creation of the variable `reportsArray` presents an error as follows `Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.` What's best to do here, ignore the error or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is no read rule here. When you establish $firebaseArray() it attempts to read the data from the server. If you aren't going to display the data on the client, you don't need $firebaseArray (i.e. bindings for use in an Angular view), just call the Firebase push() method directly.

Comment: Thanks Kato, will do.

Comment: Try the Bolt compiler for your security rules. It makes things a lot easier. https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-11-09-introducing-the-bolt-compiler.html

Comment: Thanks David I will take a look at that.